# Create a hash of arrays from CSV with jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have the following CSV (truncated):

```
"adfebb","a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","95-00123","C560","USAF"
"ae0133","a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","97-00102","C560","USAF"
```

I need the following JSON:

```
{
    "adfebb":["a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","95-00123","C560","USAF"],
    "ae0133":["a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","97-00102","C560","USAF"]
}
```

I have been tinkering with jq and came close but I haven't managed to get it just right. What I currently have is:

```
jq -R '
    inputs
    | . / "\n"
    | (.[] | select(length > 0) | . / ",") as $fields
    | [$fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4]] as $aircraft
    | {($fields[0]): $aircraft}
    
' >outfile.json
```

That produces

```
{
    "adfebb":["a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","95-00123","C560","USAF"]
}
{
    "ae0133":["a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","97-00102","C560","USAF"]
}
```

(Note the missing comma)...

I'm clearly missing something but I'm at the end of my wits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `. / ","` you are splitting at any occurring comma, regardless of it actually separating the columns, or being part of a column value. If you can assert that the latter won't happen (data never contains commas), here's an approach using `reduce` to successively build up your target object:

```bash
jq -nR 'reduce (inputs / "," | map(fromjson)) as $i ({}; .[$i[0]] = $i[1:])'
```

```json
{
  "adfebb": [
    "a-f-A-M-F-R-Z",
    "95-00123",
    "C560",
    "USAF"
  ],
  "ae0133": [
    "a-f-A-M-F-R-Z",
    "97-00102",
    "C560",
    "USAF"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That actually gives me `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index object with number`

Comment: @StefanGofferje I cannot reproduce your error. Can you cross-check your run with this [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/L5NFsO1Dmh-)?

Comment: Apologies, there were some missing quotes in the source file. The other solution above pointed them out. With a fixed source, your solution works also and a little bit faster, I think.

Comment: If there is a difference in performance, it could be because of multiple calls to jq. (jq has comparably heavy startup speed.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm never sure if this is the simplest way, but I would write

```
jq -R '[split(",")[] | fromjson] |
       [{key: .[0], value: .[1:]}] |
       from_entries' tmp.csv | jq -s 'add'
```

---

An explanation...

The first part of the filter produces a list of strings for each row.  (It assumes you can treat a row as a comma-separated stream of JSON strings; `jq` isn't really designed to parse CSV files.)

```
$ jq -Rc '[split(",")[]|fromjson]' tmp.csv
["adfebb","a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","95-00123","C560","USAF"]
["ae0133","a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","97-00102","C560","USAF"]
```

The second part of the filter creates a list of objects with `key` and `value` fields, using the first element of a list as the key and the remaining elements of a list as the value.

```
$ jq -Rc '[split(",")[]|fromjson] | [{key: .[0], value: .[1:]}]' tmp.csv
[{"key":"adfebb","value":["a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","95-00123","C560","USAF"]}]
[{"key":"ae0133","value":["a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","97-00102","C560","USAF"]}]
```

These lists are designed to be processed by `from_entries` to create the desired JSON objects.

```
% jq -Rc '[split(",")[]|fromjson] | [{key: .[0], value: .[1:]}] | from_entries' tmp.csv
{"adfebb":["a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","95-00123","C560","USAF"]}
{"ae0133":["a-f-A-M-F-R-Z","97-00102","C560","USAF"]}
```

The second `jq` command reads the objects into a single array, then "sums" them to create a single object with two keys.